# Progress Bar run less time than defined

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a function that gets number of milliseconds and then runs the progress bar but the result is that the progress bar run less time than defined.

```
this.timerProgress.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timerProgress_Tick);

public void AnimateProgBar(int milliSeconds)
{
    if (!timerProgress.Enabled)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pbStatus.Value = 0; });
        timerProgress.Interval = milliSeconds / 100;
        timerProgress.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timerProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pbStatus.Value < 100)
    {
        pbStatus.Value += 1;
        pbStatus.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        timerProgress.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Timer` interval **IS** in milliseconds.. you're dividing it by 100. E.g., calling `AnimateProgBar(1000)` will result in `1000 / 100` which is 10.. you're setting the interval at 10ms..

Answer (score 0):

using AnimateProgBar(100), will end up creating a Interval of 1 millisecond.

> timerProgress.Interval = milliSeconds; //do not divide by 100

```
this.timerProgress.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timerProgress_Tick);

public void AnimateProgBar(int milliSeconds)
{
    if (!timerProgress.Enabled)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pbStatus.Value = 0; });
        timerProgress.Interval = milliSeconds; //do not divide by 100
        timerProgress.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timerProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pbStatus.Value < 100)
    {
        pbStatus.Value += 1;
        pbStatus.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        timerProgress.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A call to `AnimateProgBar(1000)` will result in the following calculation: `1000 / 100`. That equals `10`.

The `Timer` interval is already in milliseconds. So you're effectively setting the interval to `10ms`.

Comment: As far as I understand OP is trying to set *whole* running time for timer and make 100 ticks in this time span.