# Progress Bar run less time than defined - continue previous post

Tags: c#, winforms

this is my post earlier: [Progress Bar run less time than defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575359/progress-bar-run-less-time-than-defined)

all the answers was that i don't need to divide the milliseconds by 100 and when i try this solution the progress bar run to slow unlike the first time that it runs to fast but i think i need to divide the milliseconds by 100 in order to set each 1% from the total 100% that the progress should run.
for example if i want my progress bar will run for 10 seconds so i i divide 10000 / 10 each 1%  (or timer tick) will need to be 100 milliseconds so even if i configure it to 100 it still to fast

```
void bittwist_progBarEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { AnimateProgBar((int)sender); });
}

public void AnimateProgBar(int milliSeconds)
{
    if (!timerProgress.Enabled)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pbStatus.Value = 0; });
        timerProgress.Interval = milliSeconds / 100;
        timerProgress.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timerProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pbStatus.Value < 100)
    {
        pbStatus.Value += 1;
        pbStatus.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        timerProgress.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

for example for `milliSeconds == 10000` the progress bar runs only for 7 seconds

Comment: `less/more time than defined` What exactly do you mean? For example: I want it to run 1 second and it runs 100/0.1 seconds?

Comment: And show the code calling `AnimateProgBar`

Comment: the number of milliseconds that i want my progress bar run

Comment: I couldn't see any problems with this code. It runs as expected on my machine: when given 10000 milliseconds progressbar gets filled in time no less than 10 seconds. That's why I suggest to double-check the value getting passed into `AnimateProgBar`. Try to hardcode every call to this method to `AnimateProgBar(10000)` and check the results.

Comment: Also, check that no other method is accessing progressbar and timer.

Comment: By the way. I assume that `pbStatus.Minimum` is 0 and `pb.Status.Maximum` is 100 here.

Comment: is it is (pbStatus.Minimum is 0 and pb.Status.Maximum is 100), thanks for your help